# Com montar um query dinamicamente dependendo de um string digitada

Tags: php, sql

Estou montando uma pesquisa no banco de dados onde o usuário informa um texto exemplo: "como configurar o windows".

Atualmente tenho um `select` que funciona da seguinte forma:

```
$query = "SELECT resposta FROM suporte where pergunta like '%".$s."%'";
```

Onde `$s` tem o valor como configurar o windows.

Minha ideia seria pegar essa *string* e quebrar palavra por palavra onde o `select` final seria:

```
SELECT resposta FROM suporte where pergunta like '%como%' and pergunta like '%configurar%' and pergunta like '%o%' and pergunta like '%windows%'
```

Alguém teria um exemplo de como proceder nesse caso?

Detalhe estou usando PHP como linguagem

Comment: Conhece o conceito de elastic search? Talvez resolva seu problema.

Comment: Seria interessante se as pessoas que negativaram a pergunta explicasse o porquê negativaram.

Comment: Olá Eder Luca, é muito importante nós informar a linguagem que você esta usando para facilitar a sua ajuda

Comment: Dependendo da linguagem você pode usar interpolação!

Comment: desculpe acabei esquecendo de comentar estou utilizando a linguagem php

Answer (score 0):

Eu coloquei como método para simplificar:

```
function constructQuerySearch($s) 
{ 
    $results = explode(' ', $s);

    $query_parse = array();
    if (count($results)) {

       $query = "SELECT resposta FROM suporte WHERE pergunta LIKE '%" . $results[0] . "%'";
       foreach($results as k =>  $result) {
            if ($k > 0) {
               $query .= ' AND ';
               $query_parse[] = "pergunta like '%$result%'"   
            }
       }
       $query . implode(' AND ', $query_parse);
    }

    return $query;
}
```

**Obs:** Mas eu usuaria "OR" ao invés de "AND", para não limitar a sua consulta.